# Перебор массива объектов

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

С сервера и с формы приходит вот такой массив:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно его перебрать ключ значение в этой компоненте:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import User from "./Users";

const UsersInfo = ({usersData}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {usersData.map((el, i) => {return(<User {...el} key={i}/>)})}
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log() 
  return {
      usersData: state.GetData.users.data
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UsersInfo);
```

Но при переходе на эту компоненту ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
Ключи в массивах одинаковые

Comment: А вы уверены что до компонента доходит именно тот объект, который вам нужен? Выведите в логе значение usersData перед return и посмотрите что там. По всей видимости до компонента доходит не массив, а undefined или объект.

Comment: Да, вывел в лог usersData в переменной UsersInfo пришел именно такой массив

Comment: У меня все равно сомнения) Попробуйте использовать условие перед выводом: usersData && usersData.map((el, i) => {return(<User {...el} key={i}/>)})

Comment: Если будет пустота, значит изначально пришел неопределенный объект. Если ошибка, то все-таки вы получили объект, но не массив. Можете еще воспользоваться Array.isArray(usersData), чтобы наверняка проверить на массив.

Comment: Увидел, да пришел undefined

Answer (score 0):

Ответ с сервера не означает, что компонент получил нужные элементы.

Здесь стоит обратить внимание на 3 момента:

1. Начальное состояние 'state'.
2. Правильность записи данных в состояние.
3. Правильность обращения к элементам в состоянии для извлечения необходимых данных.

В начале запуска скрипта необходимый элемент может быть еще не инициализирован и соответственно его значение будет undefined. Тогда при извлечении свойства будет получено исключение или значение undefined.

Чтобы этого избежать, можно заранее объявить значение элемента в дереве состояний нужным пустым значением (например, пустой массив).

```
{GetData: {users: []}}
```

Второй способ, это выполнять проверку в компоненте на неопределенность значения или соответствие типа (Array.isArray(usersData)).

```
usersData && usersData.map((el, i) => {return(<User {...el} key={i}/>)})
```

Третий способ, это использовать проверку типа с помощью PropTypes https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html и задание значение по умолчанию https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops

Answer (score 0):

Все проще чем оказалось, проблемма в переборе значений в компоненте UsersInfo.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import User from "./Users";

const UsersInfo = ({usersData}) => {
    return (
        <div>
          {usersData && usersData.map((el) => (el.data).map((el, i) => {return <User name={el.name} avatar={el.avatar} username={el.username} key={i}/>  }))}
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      usersData: state.GetData.users.data
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UsersInfo);
```

usersData имеет много вложенностей примерно так:

```
const someArr = [
    {
        data: [ {
            name: "",
            username: "",
            avatar: ""
        }
        ]  
}]
```

Если есть способ упростить перебор такого массива пишите